# What is the difference between 'English Language & Usage' and 'English Language Learners'?

Tags: support, scope, english-language-and-usage

I want to know the difference between the two Stack Exchange sites 'English Language & Usage' and 'English Language Learners' (this site).

Comment: I'll also note that none of the questions I remember you asking on EL&U were actually suitable there, and for the ones that were well-considered and well-formed enough to answer, should have been asked in the first instance here on ELL. I got the sense, with many of them, that you simply asked on EL&U because either your question wasn't well received on ELL (downvoted, closed), or you didn't get answers which satisfied you here. **You should not do that**. EL&U is not your "ELL backup plan", as Glorfindel's answer on this Q and the other answers on the exact dupe demonstrate.

Answer (score 4):

This question, originally posted on the main site, really belongs on [Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/) and has now been migrated. [This question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-question-fits-on-english-language-usage-or-on-eng) asks whether to post a question on ELL or EL&U and is a near-duplicate of this one.

The difference between the sites is explained in detail [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3723/116151), but basically it boils down to the following: this site is meant

> for speakers of other languages learning English

<sub>(from the [Tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour))</sub>

so it focuses on basic questions about grammar, word/phrase meanings, etc., which would be 'obvious' to native speakers (though this does certainly not mean they all would be able to answer them; English can be very confusing at times for no apparent reason).

On the other hand,

> English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

<sub>(from the [EL&U Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour))</sub>

While we do have a lot of questions here which would be interesting/not too basic for native/fluent English speakers (e.g. [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/224/18673)), those would fit on EL&U as well.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the example question you used for "suitable for EL&U" wasn't asked by someone trying to learn English as foreign language in the sense that most members here are. I believe Reg'a native language is indeed Russian, but he's so fluent in English he might as well be a native speaker. Maybe pick a more representative example? I will say while most of the questions I see on ELL "would never occur to me to ask" as a native speaker, I do sometimes learn a good deal from some of the *answers* here, particularly from the more academic & linguistically trained members (eg Stoney)

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for the kudos; but I have to tell you that my academic training is in theatre, and my linguistic 'training' is two undergraduate courses in historical linguistics followed fifty years later by binge-reading John Lawler's answers on ELU.